# Eigen Block wrong amount of columns and rows

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

I have a Eigen Matrix with the size 256x256.

I want to shrink it to 100x100 and want to keep the inner values so the values from index 78,78 till 178,178.

I want to do this with the block operation but I get a matrix with a wrong size. The block has 178 rows and 178 columns instead of 100 rows and columns.

```
 Eigen::MatrixXf small = Eigen::MatrixXf::Constant(100, 100, 0.0);
 small = matrix.block(78, 78, 178, 178).eval();
 cout<<small.rows()<<endl;
 cout<<small.cols()<<endl;`
```

outputs 178 and 178.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per documentation https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialBlockOperations.html :

```
matrix.block(i,j,p,q);
```

means

> Block of size (p,q), starting at (i,j)

So you need, in your case `p=q=100`,  hence something like

```
 small = matrix.block(78, 78, 100, 100).eval();
```

Answer (score 4):

You misread [the documentation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialBlockOperations.html).

The third and fourth arguments are *width* and *height*, not *X2* or *Y2*.

So, simply pass 100, 100 instead.